# Build file does not execute test

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, selenium-webdriver

This is my project structure in eclipse.Inside config all the environment properties like browser name,testurl are saved.
My problem is my tests are executed when I execute from junit file.But test fails(Browser does not start)when executing from build.xml.
Build File-

```
<property name="RELEASE_ROOT" value=".." />
<property name="SRC" value="${RELEASE_ROOT}/src" /> <!-- Change it to your source folder -->
<property name="LIB" value="${RELEASE_ROOT}/src/lib" /> <!-- Change it to your lib folder --> 
<property name="BIN" value="${RELEASE_ROOT}/bin1" /> <!-- Change it to your binary folder where you need to gerate the compiled binary file -->
<property name="REPORT" value="${RELEASE_ROOT}/report" /> <!-- Change it to your output report folder -->
<path id="test.classpath"> <!-- Creating a classpath for use while compiling -->
    <pathelement location="${BIN}" />
    <fileset dir="${LIB}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
<target name="init"> <!-- Initialization target which deletes and recreates the binary folder.-->
    <delete dir="${BIN}" />
    <mkdir dir="${BIN}" />
</target>
<target name="compile" depends="init"> <!-- Target for compiling the source folder  -->
    <javac source="1.7" srcdir="${SRC}" fork="true" destdir="${BIN}" >
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${BIN}">
            </pathelement>
            <fileset dir="${LIB}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

</target>
<target name="run-single-test" depends="compile"> <!-- Target for running a single test -->
    <delete dir="${REPORT}" />
    <mkdir dir="${REPORT}" />
        <mkdir dir="${REPORT}/xml" /> <!-- Creating a xml folder under the report folder for saving the report output. -->
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${BIN}" />
            <fileset dir="${LIB}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>

        <test name="com.bsb.portal.TopPage.script.ExecuteTest" haltonfailure="no" todir="${REPORT}/xml" outfile="TEST-result"> <!-- Change the class in name="" to your Java test class. -->
            <formatter type="xml" />
        </test>
    </junit>
    <junitreport todir="${REPORT}"> <!-- This section generated the Junit report in html to "html" folder from the xml file. -->
        <fileset dir="${REPORT}/xml">
            <include name="TEST*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${REPORT}/html" />
    </junitreport>

</target>
<target name="run-batch-test" depends="compile"> <!-- Target to run test in batches. -->
    <delete dir="${REPORT}" />
            <mkdir dir="${REPORT}" />
                <mkdir dir="${REPORT}/xml" />
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${BIN}" />
            <pathelement location="${SRC}" />
            <fileset dir="${LIB}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${REPORT}/xml">
            <fileset dir="${SRC}">
                <include name="**/Test*.java" />

            </fileset>
        </batchtest>

    </junit>
    <junitreport todir="${REPORT}">
        <fileset dir="${REPORT}/xml">
            <include name="TEST*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${REPORT}/html" />
    </junitreport>

</target>
```

Please suggest needful.

Comment: so your problem is to open the brower when unit test executed form  ant?

Comment: yes browser is not executed to start the test

Comment: What is the console output when this happens?